# Having problems with testing angular app / ERROR: 'DEPRECATION: describe with no children (describe() or it())

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

After runned my test with this artist-detail.spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { ArtistDetailComponent } from './artist-detail.component';

describe('ArtistDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: ArtistDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ArtistDetailComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      declarations: [ ArtistDetailComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ArtistDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have got this output

> 27 04 2022 18:23:06.651:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
> 27 04 2022 18:23:09.795:INFO [Chrome Headless 100.0.4896.127 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket iATQ5FHffdjRWSTWAAAB with id 92608559
> Chrome Headless 100.0.4896.127 (Linux x86_64) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION: describe with no children (describe() or it()) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Jasmine. Please either remove the describe or add children to it.
> Error:
> at 
> at Env.jasmineEnv. [as describe] (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:454:1)
> at 
> at Object.4911 (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/modules/artist/artist-detail/artist-detail.component.spec.ts:8:1)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> Note: This message will be shown only once. Set the verboseDeprecations config property to true to see every occurrence.'
> Chrome Headless 100.0.4896.127 (Linux x86_64) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION: describe with no children (describe() or it()) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Jasmine. Please either remove the describe or add children to it.
> Error:
> at 
> at Env.jasmineEnv. [as describe] (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:454:1)
> at 
> at Object.4911 (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/modules/artist/artist-detail/artist-detail.component.spec.ts:8:1)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> Note: This message will be shown only once. Set the verboseDeprecations config property to true to see every occurrence.'
> Chrome Headless 100.0.4896.127 (Linux x86_64) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION: describe with no children (describe() or it()) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Jasmine. Please either remove the describe or add children to it.
> Error:
> at 
> at Env.jasmineEnv. [as describe] (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:454:1)
> at 
> at Object.4911 (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/modules/artist/artist-detail/artist-detail.component.spec.ts:8:1)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> Note: This message will be shown only once. Set the verboseDeprecations config property to true to see every occurrence.'
> ExhibitionDetailComponent
> ✔ should create

How can I fix the issue **ERROR: 'DEPRECATION'**
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This answer doesn't directly answer the question above, but it may help others that encounter the error, since I kept ending up here when searching for a solution.

The error:

`ERROR: 'DEPRECATION: describe with no children (describe() or it())`

This can happen if an error occurs before the code hits the inner `describe` or `it` functions. So the test code never reaches the inner functions.

In my case, I was upgrading from Jasmine v1.3.1 to Jasmine v4 and I had the below code. Note that I had the incorrect Jasmine API call for `andReturn` on a spied object. So the test failed at that point before it could reach the inner `describe` function.

```js
define(function(require) {
    'use strict';
  
    return describe('Sample test', function () {  
        var saveMock = jasmine.createSpy('save').andReturn($.Deferred().resolve());

        describe('test', function() {
            it('should be true', function() {
                expect(true).toEqual(true);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Fixing the API call, then fixed the actual issue and stopped the error `describe with no children` from being thrown, since it could reach the inner `describe`

```
var saveMock = jasmine.createSpy('save').and.returnValue($.Deferred().resolve());
```

Answer (score 4):

The above deprecation warning does not tell you which test has the problem. It is just like a summary warning saying that one of the test(s) have this problem.

To found out which tests need to be fixed please add *verboseDeprecations: true* for **jasmine** in **karma.conf.js** config file (see below)

```
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        ....
        verboseDeprecations: true,
        ...
      },
      ...
    },
```

Then run all or required unit tests and see the name of each of the tests that has **describe with no children** problem and fix those (add children or remove those describe).

Answer (score 0):

Also had same error. Solved by specifying function `ìt`. Since you have 2x `beforeEach` functions I'd suggest writing it like

```
it('should create', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ArtistDetailComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a `beforeEach` and `it` blocks inside of the main `beforeEach`.

Similar to below:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
  
  beforeEach(() => {});
  
  it('abc', () => {});
  it('def', () => {});
});
```

I changed it to:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
});

beforeEach(() => {});

it('abc', () => {});

it('def', () => {});
```

And the issue went away.